# High Type 1 Errors in Power Analysis by Simulation for Null Effect with Multilevel Ordinal Regression with Cumulative Link Model

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, statistical-power, ordered-logit

I am doing a power analysis for an experiment where we will fit a cumulative link model for ordinal regression. But when I do the power analysis, my power for the null effect is between 20% and 30%. It should be under 5% right?

**The experiment**
We have groups who play a game over 20 rounds, and each round they come to a decision that can be expressed as an integer between 0 to 6. The game is played in one of two conditions.

**The model**

Dependent variable:

- Decision (integer between 0 and 6).

Independent variables:

- Round number (integer between 1 and 20).
- Indicator variable for condition 2. Boolean.

Random Effects:

- Group level intercept. Float. Modelled as normally distributed across groups.

**Hypothesis**
My hypothesis is that the decision points will overall be higher in condition 2. To test for that, I am predicting that the condition indicator variable will be positive.

I am using the R ordinal package and the clmm2 model fitter, e.g.

```
model <- clmm2(decision ~ round + condition_indicator, random=group_id, data = df, Hess=TRUE)
```

I am running a power analysis by simulating groups. I am using model parameters from some pilot data.

My full code is below:

```
library(ordinal)

THRESHOLDS = c(-4.0924, -2.8361, -1.7731, -0.4140, 1.5865, 4.2400)
BETA_ROUND = -0.1203
BETA_INDICATOR = 0
GROUP_RANDOM_EFFECT_SD <- 1

simulate_decision <- function(round, group_constant, indicator) {
  # Use the reverse logit link function to calculate cumulative probabilities for each decision
  A = THRESHOLDS - BETA_ROUND*round - BETA_INDICATOR*indicator - group_constant
  cum_probs<- exp(A)/(1+exp(A))
  # Use a uniform random number to choose a decision
  random_p <- runif(1)
  decision <- findInterval(random_p, cum_probs)
  return (decision)  
}

simulate_group <- function(group_constant, indicator) {
  # Simulate one group's data - decisions for each of 20 rounds
  rounds <- 1:20
  round_decisions <- sapply(rounds, simulate_decision, 
                          indicator = indicator,
                          group_constant = group_constant)
  return (round_decisions)
}

simulate_experiment <- function() {
  # Simulate an entire experiment, with groups in different conditions
  # Create a df to store the simulated data
  df <- data.frame(round = integer(), decision = integer(), group_id = integer())
  
  n_condition_A <- 30
  n_condition_B <- 30
  
  # Generate data for condition A
  for(i in 1:n_condition_A) {
    # Draw a group level random effect
    group_constant <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = GROUP_RANDOM_EFFECT_SD)
    # Simulate the group decision at each round
    group_result <- simulate_group(group_constant=group_constant, indicator=FALSE)
    temp_df <- data.frame(round = 1:20, decision = group_result, group_id = rep(i, 20), condition_indicator = rep(FALSE, 20))
    df <- rbind(df, temp_df)
  }
  
  # Generate data for condition B
  for(i in 1:n_condition_B) {
    # Draw a group level random effect
    group_constant <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = GROUP_RANDOM_EFFECT_SD)
    # Simulate the group decision at each round
    group_result <- simulate_group(group_constant=group_constant, indicator=TRUE)
    temp_df <- data.frame(round = 1:20, decision = group_result, group_id = rep(i, 20), condition_indicator = rep(TRUE, 20))
    df <- rbind(df, temp_df)
  }
  
  # Convert data format fur use in ordinal package
  df$decision <- as.factor(df$decision)
  df$group_id <- as.factor(df$group_id)
  # Fit the cumulative link model
  model <- clmm2(decision ~ round + condition_indicator, random=group_id, data = df, Hess=TRUE)
  summary(model)  
  return (summary(model)$coefficients)
}

estimate_power <- function() {
  # Simulate the experiment lots of times and count how many times it is significant
  sig_count <- 0 
  n_sims <- 50
  for (sim_count in 1:n_sims) {
    print(paste0("Running ", sim_count, " of ", n_sims))
    result <- simulate_experiment()
    # We are interested in the p-value and value of the indicator variable coefficient
    p <- result[8,4]
    beta <- result[8,1]
    # One sided significance test
    if (p<0.025 & beta > 0) {
      print("Was significant!")
      sig_count <- sig_count + 1
    }  
  }
  estimated_power <- sig_count / n_sims
  return (estimated_power)
}

estimate_power()
```

Comment: When presenting code to state a problem the code needs to be easy to follow.  Your code uses methods that are too indirect and too bulky.  For example you can specify cell probabilities and generate samples directly from a multinomial distribution using `sample` or `rmultinom`.  You can apply an odds ratio to cell probabilities to get new probabilities to simulate from using for example the `pomodm` function as done [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#discrete-y).  But try doing all this first without random effects (RE). I've seen failures of approximations with `ordinal` with RE.

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell. I will try and make the code simpler (I definitely appreciate your point, I'm relatively new to R and this was as simple as I could manage).  Yes the problem goes away when I remove the random effects.

Comment: I recently had a case with 100 persons each with 2 measurements and used random intercepts with `ordinal`.  The results were silly, whereas using a linear model with random effects (not recommended if ordinal Y is not really also an interval-scaled variable) was perfectly fine.  I think that some of the high-dimensional integration approximations used with nonlinear models' random effects are dubious.  I hope someone can find references about that.

Comment: Thank you. Yes my working hypothesis is that some of the group level variation is being assigned to variation between conditions. I've searched and cannot find a reference yet. I'll post here if I do. My Y variable is interval spaced so maybe I will use a linear model instead.

Comment: When I used random effects in a Bayesian ordinal model everything behaved properly.  The Bayesian approach doesn't need approximations.